# Combining Inline Edit with Create mode for new entries?

Tags: forms, web-app

With inline edit I'm trying to provide a quick way to edit entries. However I feel that inline editing to create new entries is not intuitive (and would need to provide defaults) so I created a separate edit mode.

Do you think it's a good practice to combine these 2 different data entry modes?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ou2j.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: When your entries are as simple as in your sketch, I think @jensgram is right and you can safely provide inline editing for creating new entries. But if they're actually more complex, then combining the two modes is acceptable.

Comment: You're right it should remain simple enough in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not replicate the inline interface for each entry ("experience")? As for the defaults, you could simply use the labels.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCZnrL.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Also note that this will make it easy to provide affordances for sorting and/or deletion:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0H55.png)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jensgram. I still had doubts but your mock makes it more clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

I Like jensgram's approach. Another approach which I have seen which is used commonly is to have a number of textboxes in a horizontal layout which can be used to add a new field

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhdXFA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: sounds fine. only drawback of this approach for this particular case is that it requires columns. In my case it's more of a text whose some words you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I usually work in multi-language systems. Is your system multi-language as well? That would not have worked in Turkish as well as English. It is better to edit and view from the same type of structure. I would also guess that the "fill in the blanks" approach would work better.

Comment: If you can improve the answer, for instance telling us why that woudln work it would be much better.

Comment: Fair point... Well.. in Turkish the way the sentences are built is different than in English. For example in English we say "since 2007" and in Turkish we say "2007'den beri" and the suffix after 2007 changed to "2010'dan beri" according to the last letter of the last word (number in this case). So if you base your system on a language that is based on word groups for conjugation sure it works but in languages that conjugate in suffix; sentences can be tricky.